# Identify Inf in sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

How does one identify `Inf`, `-Inf` when using SQL with `sqldf`?

Sample data:

```
x <- data.frame(val = c(1, 2, 3, Inf))
```

Now, I am using:

```
sqldf('select * from x where val < 999999999999999999999')
```

But this does not seem very safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
> sqldf("select val from x where cast(val as text) != 'Inf'")
  val
1   1
2   2
3   3
```